# Wrong padding when using 'm' column in table with `\lipsum`

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

I'm having some troubles with the 'm' column type in my tables. For some reason when using the `m` column type the content is offset bit to the top causing the top padding to be reduced and the bottom padding to be increased resulting in an ugly looking table.

I found several questions regarding this topic but none of these seams to be using tabu with `\tabulinesep` and `\cellcolor`. So I'm adding this question to the list:

How do I get proper vertical centering in a `tabu` table?

## Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{HTML}{015093}
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{EBF0F5}

\tabulinesep1em

\begin{document}

\section{Correct padding}

\begin{tabu}{X[1,c] |[0.5em,white] X[5,c]}
    \cellcolor{darkBlue}\textcolor{white}{Lorem ipsum} &
    \cellcolor{lightBlue}\lipsum[5] \\
\end{tabu}

\section{Wrong padding when using 'm' column}

\begin{tabu}{X[1,c,m] |[0.5em,white] X[5,c,m]}
    \cellcolor{darkBlue}\textcolor{white}{Lorem ipsum} &
    \cellcolor{lightBlue}\lipsum[5] \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of the rendere latex document]

Comment: It's seems that is not faulty of tabu. Try to replace `lipsum` width `blindtext` and you will receive in the both cases (with `m` and without it) the same result.

Comment: It is always a good idea to surround `\lipsum`  with some normal text to avoid side effects from the internal code `abc \lipsum[5] abc`.

Comment: Oh my. You are right. I was having troubles with my longtable and prepared a testcase using tabu and lipsum just to run across that weird vertical alignment issue.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\lipsum*` that doesn't add a trailing `\par`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{HTML}{015093}
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{EBF0F5}

\tabulinesep1em

\begin{document}

\section{Correct padding}

\begin{tabu}{X[1,c] |[0.5em,white] X[5,c]}
    \cellcolor{darkBlue}\textcolor{white}{Lorem ipsum} &
    \cellcolor{lightBlue}\lipsum*[5] \\
\end{tabu}

\section{Correct padding also when using 'm' column}

\begin{tabu}{X[1,c,m] |[0.5em,white] X[5,c,m]}
    \cellcolor{darkBlue}\textcolor{white}{Lorem ipsum} &
    \cellcolor{lightBlue}\lipsum*[5] \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Zarko** and **Ulrike Fischer** for pointing out that this is caused by `\lipsum` rather than `\tabu` and the `m` column type.

## Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{HTML}{015093}
\definecolor{lightBlue}{HTML}{EBF0F5}

\tabulinesep1em

\newcommand\mytext[0]{
Fusce mauris. Vestibulum luctus nibh at lectus. Sed
bibendum, nulla a faucibus semper, leo velit ultricies tellus,
ac venenatis arcu wisi vel nisl. Vestibulum diam. Aliquam
pellentesque, augue quis sagittis posuere, turpis lacus
congue quam, in hendrerit risus eros eget felis. Maecenas
eget erat in sapien mattis porttitor. Vestibulum porttitor.
Nulla facilisi. Sed a turpis eu lacus commodo facilisis.
Morbi fringilla, wisi in dignissim interdum, justo lectus
sagittis dui, et vehicula libero dui cursus dui. Mauris
tempor ligula sed lacus. Duis cursus enim ut augue. Cras
ac magna. Cras nulla. Nulla egestas. Curabitur a leo.
Quisque egestas wisi eget nunc. Nam feugiat lacus vel est.
Curabitur consectetuer.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{X[1,c,m] |[0.5em,white] X[5,c,m]}
    \cellcolor{darkBlue}\textcolor{white}{Lorem ipsum} &
    \cellcolor{lightBlue}\mytext \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]